# How to get system charset in Rust on Windows?

Tags: rust

Working on Rust connector for TDengine, my problem is to get system charset in Rust. Which crate or which method should I use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ANSI codepage (that used for 8-bit text applications), use [`GetACP()`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Globalization/fn.GetACP.html). To get the OEM codepage (that used in consoles) use [`GetOEMCP()`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Globalization/fn.GetOEMCP.html).

I don't know that TDengine, but to keep your sanity you should avoid ANSI/OEM codepages and use UTF-8/Unicode whenever possible. The Rust [`OsString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html) type makes this somewhat less painful.